# Error message when plotting truncated normal distribution with fitditrplus

Tags: r, distribution, truncated, fitdistrplus, mass

I am trying to plot different distributions to see which best fits my data ("x"). I am using package fitdistrplus to do this. All the distributions work apart from "tnorm" (truncated normal distribution), which comes up with an error message:

```
fit_tn<-fitdist(x,"tnorm",start=list(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)),fix.arg=list(a=0,b=Inf))
$start.arg
$start.arg$mean
[1] 28.61737

$start.arg$sd
[1] 29.45779


$fix.arg
$fix.arg$a
[1] 0

$fix.arg$b
[1] Inf


Error in fitdist(x, "tnorm", start = list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)),  :
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters,
                with the error code 10
```

Any ideas what is causing this error message and how to fix it?

Any help much appreciated!!!

Distributions that are working:

```
fit_ex<-fitdist(x,"exp")
fit_nm<-fitdist(x,"norm")
fit_ln<-fitdist(x,"lnorm")
fit_gm<-fitdist(x,"gamma")
fit_wb<-fitdist(x,"weibull")
```

packages used:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(extraDistr)
library(actuar)
```

Some info about my data:

```
min(x)
[1] 1
max(x)
[1] 235
length(x)
[1] 426
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is 10 and not 100?

Comment: yep, definitely says 10!

Comment: If I change the "a" to 1 and "b" to 235 it says error code 100 if that helps?

Comment: It might be referring to optimizer error 10, `indicates degeneracy of the Nelder–Mead simplex`, but thats well beyond my understanding.